# Adding multiple OpenIdConnect authentication schemes to the services and choosing at runtime which to use

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, startup, microsoft-entra-id

I have a Asp.net core mvc project that uses the OpenIdConnect authentication scheme with the Microsoft Identity platform. The way I add it is in my Startup class in ConfigureServices method like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    // Removed everything else for briefity.
}
```

The AzureAd configuration section looks like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomain.com",
  "ClientId": "X",
  "TenantId": "Y",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

This works splendidly and the [Authorize] attribute on the actions in the controllers prompt the user to log in using Microsoft account. But I want to be able to add multiple AzureAd config sections and decide at runtime which section to use to log in the user.

Example of how it might look like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd1"));
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd2"));
    // Removed everything else for briefity.
}
```

and:

```
"AzureAd1": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomain1.com",
  "ClientId": "X1",
  "TenantId": "Y1",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"AzureAd2": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomain2.com",
  "ClientId": "X2",
  "TenantId": "Y2",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

and then in the controller instead of decorating the methods with attribute [Authorize], or maybe keep it, I would do something like so:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    var x = GetX();
    var azureAdSettings = _azureAdSettings.GetSettings(x);
    // Set authentication based on the azureAdSettings for x.
}
```

Maybe it should be done in the constructor instead and set a scoped context.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to let the user choose which Azure AD tenant to login or just want to select the Azure AD setting during selecting the runtime environment variable like Product or development?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I guess my problem is very similar to letting the user choosing the tenant and application. But in my case I would be choosing it for the user based on parameters read during runtime. The user would be non the wiser. So when some user navigates to a certain website then the code would decide which tenant and application id settings to use for that user at runtime.

Comment: You mean it will contain one page which let the user select which tenant to access and then redirect to MSFT login page?

Comment: I am not trying to be rude but does it matter how the UI will be? When users navigate to x.something.com I want to use the tenant for x and when users navigate to y.something.com then I want to use the tenant for y. The problem is that I register the Azure settings in the startup class and I do not know if it is possible to change it at runtime or not.